# How to get creation date of gmail account in Google OAuth 2

Tags: oauth-2.0, google-oauth

I am working on `Google OAuth 2.0`, to get information about the users logged in through `Google OAuth 2.0`. There is a variety of scopes available like

For getting the user basic profile there is OAuth scope available called `profile` which is internally converts to a URL `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.profile` and for knowing the logged in user's email id there is a Oauth scope called `email` which results in URL `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email`.

Now my question is: How to get the creation date of the gmail account of an user?

Is there any OAuth scope available for getting how old the gmail account of logged in user?

Comment: I would guess not. If it's not listed in the [scope documentation](https://developers.google.com/+/api/oauth) then there's no reason to expect it exists. It doesn't seem like something that would be a common requirement and it's not part of standard OpenID Connect user info.

Comment: But in my project to eliminate fake gmail user who has registered just before one or two months, we want to check that registered date of gmail id.

Comment: If the information isn't available to then there's not much you can do. Besides, what do you mean by a "fake" gmail user? There's no guarantee that the data is "real" (represents a real person) based on the registration date. Plus you would be banning real people who just signed up for gmail within the previous two months.

Comment: According to my application requirement a user is fake if he registered into gmail just before 2 or 3 months

Comment: I think Jagadeesh has an app that has a trial period but the users constantly register with a newly created e-mail to avoid paying for the service. It would be nice to have a web-based identity that ensures this cannot happen.

Comment: Probably the easiest is to add some feature that is only available for pro accounts. (or do feature degradation such as a watermark on free samples)

Answer (score 3):

According to [Google API](https://developers.google.com/+/web/api/rest/latest/people) People resource , It doesn't have a property to check the creation date. It might be a security risk as when user forget the password, Google asks for the registration date of account.